# Display the username in a view on a relation with 2 models

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a User Model with 'username' and a Posts Model with 'user_id' as foreign key. How can I display the Username in a view?

```
/user.rb/
has_many :posts

/posts.rb/
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

I want to use it in the 'show' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= post.user.username %>
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x46a5980>:0x46a4780>

Comment: You're going to have to give more information about your code, the view etc.